# cURL won't process the login?

Tags: php, curl

So i'm trying to login from my website to `ROBLOX` using the following script

```
function login($url,$username,$password){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    $data = array(
            'userName'        => $username,
            'password'        => $password,
            'isCaptchaOn'     => false,
            'challenge'       => '',
            'captchaResponse' => ''
        );
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}
```

However when i do try the login function, it doesn't work

```
echo(login("https://www.roblox.com/newlogin","Username=teachinglover&Password=ya"));
```

It just echos nothing, and the function doesn't complete

Any idea why it isn't doing anything? and why it isn't completing the login?!

**Edit: I'm not sure but is it possible i need to add some headers?!**

if you'd like to take a look at the neccessary POST objects

```
Request URL:https://www.roblox.com/newlogin
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:8.42.96.25:443
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://www.roblox.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-CSRF-TOKEN
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:11961
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 26 Feb 2016 13:48:06 GMT
P3P:CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:38
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:RBXSource=rbx_acquisition_time=2/17/2016 11:34:48 AM&rbx_acquisition_referrer=&rbx_medium=Direct&rbx_source=&rbx_campaign=&rbx_adgroup=&rbx_keyword=&rbx_matchtype=&rbx_send_info=1; RBXViralAcquisition=time=2/17/2016 11:34:48 AM&referrer=&originatingsite=; GuestData=UserID=-1661021767; RBXMarketing=FirstHomePageVisit=1; __gads=ID=85bb563f4079b12f:T=1455730802:S=ALNI_MbDjPeXjVm69YJMcFdVnOyw2XxWvQ; __ssid=aaf89930-bda3-4057-9fed-d5324ec16615; __RequestVerificationToken=NnycdFxv3QtmdyJPW9irh64pVurQGL4BHEjZI9kq3uET0G_NT_f0JUQlIhVsE6gUC5clWd4QoPQ3gwwDo45kif1JQHw1; glt_3_OsvmtBbTg6S_EUbwTPtbbmoihFY5ON6v6hbVrTbuqpBs7SyF_LQaJwtwKJ60sY1p=LT3_p97tsEiCJbASoKTsdz1ye4a8igDizZThXseKb-HwEYg%7CUUID%3D4169b82697734de882c125e3b3e4bc17; _gig_llp=facebook; _gig_llu=Baheeg; RBXEventTrackerV2=CreateDate=2/26/2016 4:01:29 AM&rbxid=96092679&browserid=4151477874; __qca=P0-1972999082-1456481070051; rbx-ip=; RBXImageCache=timg=62646533346162632D643361312D343366392D396536622D386432646561316636313662253130392E3137372E32382E32323425322F32362F3230313620393A35313A353820414D534CED27903239AA1175AB86097D565F4BC07C53; __utmt_b=1; __utma=200924205.672426321.1455730486.1456480004.1456494511.46; __utmb=200924205.4.7.1456494511; __utmc=200924205; __utmz=200924205.1456426636.42.6.utmcsr=forum.roblox.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/Forum/ShowPost.aspx
Host:www.roblox.com
Origin:https://www.roblox.com
Referer:https://www.roblox.com/newlogin
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
Username:Test
Password:Test
ReturnUrl:
```

Comment: you pass "userName" and "password" instead of "Username" and "Password". another thing, which wont fix it,  is that you already return something and still try to execute some code after that. and your login function expects second parameter to be username, and third parameter to be the password. you pass a string with username and password in the second parameter